# Serve json file from GO server to javascript client

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-app-engine, go

I have a go server which has to respond to a javascript request by serving a json file. The json file is an array of objects.

My code :

**Server side**

```
package expt

import (
    "net/http"
)


func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handleStatic)
    http.HandleFunc("/loadTrials", handleloadJson)
}

func handleStatic(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "static/"+r.URL.Path)
}


func handleloadJson(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "static/trial.json")
}
```

**Client side**

```
loadTrials : function loadTrials() {

            var _this = this,
                load = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#load-trial');

            load.url="http://url:8080/loadTrials";
            load.go()
            load.addEventListener('core-response', function(ev) {
                console.log(ev.detail.response)
            }, false);
        }
```

**Json**

```
{
  "trial-data" : [
    {
      "trial" : {
        "index": 0,
      }
    },
    {
      "trial" : {
        "index": 1,
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If I do that I get the JSON object in JavaScript, but if I try to look into the JSON to get the array- i.e. console.log(ev.detail.response['trial-data']) then this doesn't work.

Comment: Please define _"this doesn't work"_ . What happens? You get JavaScript error? If so, what is it you get?

Comment: if i do `console.log(ev.detail.response)` I get json as string, but if I try to do `console.log(ev.detail.response['trial-data'])` I got undefined, so it means that `ev.detail.response` does not return an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ev.detail.response` is just a string response, it is not a parsed json object.

First you need to parse it using [`JSON.parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466(v=vs.85).aspx) and then you can access its content.

See this Javascript example:

```
var json = '{"trial-data":[{"trial":{"index": 0}},{"trial":{"index":1}}]}'

alert(JSON.parse(json)['trial-data'])
```

To access the value of the first `"index"` field, for example:

```
var idx0 = JSON.parse(json)['trial-data'][0]['trial']['index']
```